# Rails 3-level association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My data model:

- Collection belongs to User.
- Collection has many arts.
- Art belongs to Collection.

Rails models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end

class Collection < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :arts
  belongs_to :user
end

class Art < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :collection
end
```

problem code:

```
def index
  @arts = Art.where(:user => current_user)
end
```

Error message:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: arts.user: SELECT "arts".* FROM   "arts" WHERE "arts"."user" = 1
```

I have already added the `art_id` and the `user_id` to the Collection table as indexes and run `rake db:migrate`.

I also tried

```
has_many :arts, :through => :collections
```

in the User model but still got the error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct link between an `Art` and a `User`, so you cannot simply query arts by the non-existent field `user`.

If you want to find all art that belongs to a given user, you need to join through the `collections` table, which is the only thing that binds a user to art:

```
Art.joins(:collection => :user).where(users: { id: current_user.id })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
has_many :arts, :through => :collections
```

In your User model then use

> current_user.arts

for getting all arts of a user.

If still you are getting error then use following query

> Art.joins(:collection).where('collections.user_id = ?', current_user.id)

This should do the job.

Answer (score -1):

For the query

```
@arts = Art.where(:user => current_user)
```

You need to have user_id in Art.

i.e you need to have

```
class Art < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :collection
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: This is a fundamental change to the datamodel, and an unnecessary one. There is no need to add a redundant `user_id` to `Art`.